# Integration of a Term thats not a Function

Tags: calculus, functions

Had a math test today wih the following question
Find the anti derivative of the following: e^(5x)
So instinctively I thought not to include the +c because there is no f(x)= or y=, therefor it is not a function.
Instead I answered with e(^5x)/5 and my teacher took off half a point for not adding the +c.

Is this actually an error on my part or an error on his?

Comment: half a point out of $1$ point?

Comment: $e^{5x}$ actually _is_ a function of $x$. Furthermore, a constant is added to an integral when it has no explicit domain (also called indefinite integral, or antiderivative), for example $\int e^{5x}$. No constant is needed when you know the limits of the integral, as in $\int_0^1 e^{5x}$

Comment: "*there is no f(x)= or y=, therefor it is not a function*"... you may be interested to read about [abuse of notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuse_of_notation#Functional_notation).  Through abuse of notation, it is commonly intended that when we say $e^{5x}$ we in reality mean the function $f~:~\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ where $x\mapsto f(x)=e^{5x}$, even if it is not explicitly stated.

Comment: The word "antiderivate" only makes sense, if $e^{5x}$ is the function (depending on $x$), for which we want to calculate the antiderivate. The word "the" in "the antiderivate" is a bad choice because the antiderivate is not unique. Limits are not given, so a definite integral cannot be the intent of the exercise. Nevertheless, since it is standard that the "+c" is added in the case of an indefinite integral, I think the teacher is right, but he could have formulated the exercise more clear